# pandas fill empty cells from a column with random range number or index number

Tags: excel, pandas, random, fillna

read a excel file and i take the dataframe.
The empty cells from excel now appears with NaN.
For a column i try fill each one NaN cells with a random number with range (10000,100000)

```
import random
all_df.loc[all_df["name"].isnull(),'name'] = random.randrange(10000,100000)
```

### but with this fill NaN cells from this column with one random number all NaN cells

another column with NaN cells i try fill them with index number of row

```
all_df.loc[all_df["name"].isnull(),'name'] = all_df["name"].index.values
```

can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: `m=all_df["name"].isnull() ; all_df.loc[m, 'name'] = np.random.randint(10000, 100000, size=m.sum())`

Comment: Thank you !!! it works...
can you help me fill NaN cells with index number?

Comment: `all_df['name'].fillna(all_df.index)`?